# Does CGGlyph depend on the font size?

Tags: ios7, core-text, typesetting

CGGlyph is a typedef for unsigned short.
Every font can (or at least could) specify a different CGGlyph value for the same character. But within the same font, will the value of CGGlyph depend on the font size?

Basically I want to show the same character with different font sizes. Can I set the font size with CGContextSetFontSize() and reuse the CGGlyph value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGGlyph holds the *index* of a glyph inside a font. This is because inside a font, the order of *glyphs* (individual character designs) can be anything -- in particular, unrelated to the *character code* it represents.

That is, the order of characters in fonts is unrelated to any encoding. The character code of an "A" is 65 (in ASCII) but that does not mean "the 65th character in a font is the glyph "A". For Unicode it's nearly impossible to make it work that way: the Unicode of a curly left double quote, for example, is U+201C, or 8220 in decimal.

So there are one or more tables inside each font that translate between the *logical* index of a glyph (simply counting characters as they appear in the file itself) and one or more *encodings*. (Where an encoding is a predefined set, such as "Unicode", "MacRoman", or "Windows Latin1".)

This has several advantages: first of all, the characters in a font file don't need to appear in any particular order. The font designer can add as many encodings to the file as needed. Also, it's perfectly possible for a font to contain glyphs that appear in no encoding at all (think of rare ligatures).

All said and done:

> Every font can (or at least could) specify a different CGGlyph value for the same character.

Neither *can* nor *should*. Since CGGlyph is an *index* value, it simply always starts at 0 and the last valid valid is the number of characters in the font, minus 1.

The index of a glyph is **not** determined by its size, which is set at a very different level. So indeed you can re-use the value for different sizes.
But, noteworthy: the index of a particular character **is** uniquely tied to one **font** only. The ordering of individual characters inside each font should be considered unique (if only because one font may contain more or less charcaters than another).

See [CGGlyph toUniChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238804/osx-cgglyph-to-unichar) for a related discussion.