# How to get all characters of the font with CTFontCopyCharacterSet() in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-text

How does one get all characters of the font with `CTFontCopyCharacterSet()` in Swift? ... for macOS?

The issue occured when implementing the approach from an [OSX: CGGlyph to UniChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238804/osx-cgglyph-to-unichar/18239177#18239177) answer in Swift.

```swift
func createUnicodeFontMap() {
    // Get all characters of the font with CTFontCopyCharacterSet().
    let cfCharacterSet: CFCharacterSet = CTFontCopyCharacterSet(ctFont)

    //    
    let cfCharacterSetStr = "\(cfCharacterSet)"
    print("CFCharacterSet: \(cfCharacterSet)")  

    // Map all Unicode characters to corresponding glyphs
    var unichars = [UniChar](…NYI…) // NYI: lacking unichars for CFCharacterSet
    var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeating: 0, count: unichars.count)
    guard CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(
        ctFont, // font: CTFont
        &unichars, // characters: UnsafePointer<UniChar>
        &glyphs, // UnsafeMutablePointer<CGGlyph>
        unichars.count // count: CFIndex
        )
        else {
            return
    }

    // For each Unicode character and its glyph, 
    // store the mapping glyph -> Unicode in a dictionary.
    // ... NYI
}
```

What to do with `CFCharacterSet` to retrieve the actual characters has been elusive.  Autocompletion of the `cfCharacterSet` instance offers show no relavant methods.

[image]

And the [Core Foundation > CFCharacterSet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfcharacterset-rvm) appears have methods for creating another CFCharacterSet, but not something the provides an array|list|string of unichars to be able to create a mapped dictionary.

---

Note: I'm looking for a solution which is not specific to iOS as in [Get all available characters from a font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592139/get-all-available-characters-from-a-font) which uses `UIFont`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CFCharacterSet` is toll-free bridged with the Cocoa Foundation counterpart `NSCharacterSet`, and can be bridged to the corresponding Swift value type `CharacterSet`:

```
let charset = CTFontCopyCharacterSet(ctFont) as CharacterSet
```

Then the approach from [NSArray from NSCharacterSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741631/nsarray-from-nscharacterset/15742659#15742659) can be used to enumerate all Unicode scalar values of that character set (including non-BMP points, i.e. Unicode scalar values greater than U+FFFF).

The `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters()` expects non-BMP characters as surrogate pair, i.e. as an array of UTF-16 code units.

Putting it together, the function would look like this:

```
func createUnicodeFontMap(ctFont: CTFont) ->  [CGGlyph : UnicodeScalar] {

    let charset = CTFontCopyCharacterSet(ctFont) as CharacterSet

    var glyphToUnicode = [CGGlyph : UnicodeScalar]() // Start with empty map.

    // Enumerate all Unicode scalar values from the character set:
    for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where charset.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
        for unicode in UTF32Char(plane) << 16 ..< UTF32Char(plane + 1) << 16 {
            if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), charset.contains(uniChar) {

                // Get glyph for this `uniChar` ...
                let utf16 = Array(uniChar.utf16)
                var glyphs = [CGGlyph](repeating: 0, count: utf16.count)
                if CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(ctFont, utf16, &glyphs, utf16.count) {
                    // ... and add it to the map.
                    glyphToUnicode[glyphs[0]] = uniChar
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return glyphToUnicode
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.

```swift
let cs = CTFontCopyCharacterSet(font) as NSCharacterSet
let bitmapRepresentation = cs.bitmapRepresentation
```

The format of the bitmap is defined in the reference page for [CFCharacterSetCreateWithBitmapRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542964-cfcharactersetcreatewithbitmapre?language=objc)

Comment: `as CharacterSet`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset would also lead to the  `.bitmapRepresentation` approach.

Comment: Good to know. Also worth mentioning that using the `bitmapRepresentation` you can be quite a bit more efficient than the accepted answer; it has to loop through 65535 unicodes for each plane. Using bitmap representation you can skip groups of 8 - 64 by comparing a `UInt8` - `UInt64` at an index in the buffer to zero. Then you can skip regions that have no codes in them.

Comment: Interesting. I was unfamiliar with the `bitmapRepresentation` data format so, next steps to a mapped dictionary of UnicodeScalar was TBD... although likely not difficult. A secondary, longer term goal is have some [CGFont and CTFont functionality in portable Swift (e.g. Ubuntu, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782036/cgfont-and-ctfont-functionality-in-portable-swift-e-g-ubuntu-etc). My workaround, for now, (and use case for this question) is a one-time pass to extract some desired font metrics to a portable format. I may revisit this approach if better performance is needed. Thx.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea if the time taken to do either approach would ever be significant, just thought I'd mention it for completeness sake.

Comment: Just enumerating the character set of "Helvetiva“ takes 6 milliseconds on my MacBook. – Btw, note that planes 1...15 in the bitmapRepresentation are not aligned at 8 byte boundaries, that must be taken care of when interpreting the data as UInt64 numbers.

Comment: @MartinR Good to know! I agree that once you're down in that range the user isn't even going to notice.